# Angular app on s3 static hosting not loading node_modules or routes

Tags: angular, amazon-s3

I just added my whole project to an s3 bucket and then enabled static hosting. Then I created a cloudfront distribution. If I go to the index.html page, i'm definitely in the right path and it's  because I can see the code behind the page in page source including the `<app-root></app-root>`
but app-root doesn't load. If I go to my login page manually by inputting path through address bar and it looks like image below
So the node_modules don't appear to be loading correctly. Is there something I need to do to make it work with s3 static hosting?

[image]

Current Error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>2A294FA4E6273F46</RequestId><HostId>O91Pf+yAJFN0gC74L3Wmiacn11pxJL3d3UrWtSaEbKF0PU3N/xYbASk4niU5FYZnLbM4tVh7tHw=</HostId></Error>
```

Comment: only put your build output in your s3 folder at it's root. nothing else. looks like you have all sorts of IAM issues though.

Comment: I updated the bucket policy allow only my ip /32 to have access and now the page is loading properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deploying your entire project folder will not make it work. You have to build your project, preferably in production mode (`ng build --prod`), and then deploy just the artifact, usually created in `dist`folder to you host. Here is the documentation for more details. https://angular.io/guide/deployment#basic-deployment-to-a-remote-server

Comment: I did ng build and did a git push, which codepipeline updated my s3 bucket with.   So now I have dist folder in s3, but if put the full path ast he origin domain name. See pic above as reference, I get access denied. Do you know what's wrong?

Comment: I've never built a complete angular app before. You got me in the right direction with ng build so thank you. I'm one step closer. Page is loading correctly. Now I just have to get backend deployed lol